# Is it possible to read/write primitive types from DataStore without flows?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-datastore

Is it possible to just read/write primitive types from a `DataStore`? For example, I just want to read an `Int`. I do not want any `Flow` wrapped around it. Just plain `Int`.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused around the concept. The data store only stores primitives. A flow is just a way to collect that primitive's value over time.

Comment: How to store primitives? I cannot find any guidance to do that. All the docs are full of `Flow`s.

Comment: The documentation on writing doesn't have any mention of flows: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-write

Comment: @HenryTwist you are right about `set` functions. How about `get` functions? How to get just an `Int` from `DataStore`?

Comment: You can use the `first()` terminal operator on the flow to get the first value it emits. You can take a look at the `Flow` documentation for information on flows: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html

Comment: Reading values may require disk or other forms of I/O, so they elected to implement a reactive API, so that I/O can be performed on a background thread. The documentation offers [a demonstration of how to wrap those reactive APIs in blocking calls](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#synchronous) for cases where you cannot cope with the asynchronous results. However, as the documentation warns, "Avoid blocking threads on DataStore data reads whenever possible. Blocking the UI thread can cause ANRs or UI jank, and blocking other threads can result in deadlock."

Comment: @CommonsWare does this mean that I am not allowed to save primitives without `Flow`?

Comment: @AzizjonKholmatov As you [agreed with earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265984/is-it-possible-to-read-write-primitive-types-from-datastore-without-flows?noredirect=1#comment118897454_67265984), *saving* values does not involve `Flow`. *Retrieving* values involves `Flow` or `Flowable` (from RxJava).

Answer (score 6):

In terms of writing, flows are not used. You can save a primitive as it outlines in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-write) and unless you specify otherwise, this will be done on a background thread.

For reading, `DataStore` only returns a flow for a reason. As @CommonsWare said in the comments: "Reading values may require disk or other forms of I/O, so they elected to implement a reactive API, so that I/O can be performed on a background thread."

By using a suspend function you can just return an `Int` as you described by using the `first()` terminal operator on the flow, which returns the first value emitted.

```
suspend fun read(): Int {

    return dataStore.data.first()[KEY] ?: DEFAULT_VALUE
}
```

If you really need the call to be synchronous then you can block the thread using `runBlocking` in combination with `first()`, however as they warn in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#synchronous):

> Avoid blocking threads on DataStore data reads whenever possible. Blocking the UI thread can cause ANRs or UI jank, and blocking other threads can result in deadlock.

so if this is *necessary*, there's probably an issue with the general design of your app.

Comment: You code sample is not compiling. This is the same reason why I gave this question. I cannot figure out how to save just a plain `Int`.

Comment: I am crawling through documentation to get better idea of the design of the `DataStore`. Turns out, I completely forgot/neglected the fact that it is sometimes OK to use synchronous calls using `runBlocking`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, although I don't know where it says that it's okay to access it synchronously. I think it's highly discouraged!

Comment: I do not think we have to use asynchronous access 100% of the time. It is sometimes ok to use synchronous if it fits our case. Take a look at the link @CommonsWare provided. There it is stated that: `...but it may not always be feasible to change your surrounding code to be asynchronous. This might be the case if you're working with an existing codebase that uses synchronous disk I/O or if you have a dependency that doesn't provide an asynchronous API.`

Comment: Yes you're right, obviously if it's unavoidable there's nothing you can do. But otherwise in my opinion it would indicate am architectural problem if you felt it necessary.